# AngularJS & Firebase tutorial: 'TypeError: undefined is not a function;' issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am following a tutorial online for AngularJS. 
Of which there are several updates that amends the codes for the newer version of angularfire or firebase:

However after taking those codes in, everything started failing.

```
//For Post.js 
  var posts = $firebase(ref); 
  //var posts = $firebase(ref).$asArray(); this gives error

//For Postview.js 
    $scope.post = Post.find($stateParams.postId); 
    //$scope.post = Post.find($stateParams.postId).$asArray(); gives error when transit
```

Theres also several changes for example:

```
<!--For HTML --> 
<div class="post row" ng-repeat="(postId, post) in posts">
      <!-- <div class="post row" ng-repeat="post in posts"> gives error-->
```

Theres nothing displayed and it seems something broke while communicating with Firebase.

F12 shows the error as: "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Any thoughts? Is it because of the version of angularfire or firebase?

Comment: example how you should interact with quries: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebase-asarray

Comment: Thanks @KrzysztofSafjanowski, any idea how you would update the dependencies with node.js? I think angularfire, firebase etc. I tried to do a bower update but after updating, the versions stay the same.
Im quite convinced its a version issue whih is leading to what Felipe below is referring to.

Comment: Did you inject $firebase into your app and include it in your controller?

Comment: I did. I have resolved the issue. 
There were some issues with angular yeoman...updated angularfire through node.js cmd line but I was not aware it wasnt updated.So i did a cache for npm and updated angularfire with manual bower install through changing bower.json file manually and it did it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Thinkerer update dependencies with `node`? Are you not using bower to manage front-end dependancies?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Sorry, yes Im using bower to manage the dependencies. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well could it be that your DB query is not returning any data? This kind of error (`undefined is not a function`) generally happens when you try to call a method on a **null** object.